# what does "The default CPU and Application Binary Interface (ABI) tunings " means in yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto

I want to build a custom image for my arm board so i would like to know what are the information's in machine tune files aswellas the arch-arm files

Answer (score 1):

The Custom image for your ARM board is a collection of packages (softwares) cross-compiled using Yocto.

Yocto uses gcc to cross-compile these packages. And **gcc has options to optimize (tune) the code for a particular Architecture (armv8) and CPU (cortex-a53)**.

GCC guys have explained the Arch and CPU tuning options here -
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html#index-march

Now, **Yocto needs to know which of these tuning options need to be passed to gcc while compiling a package** for your ARM board. This is done using **Machine tune files in Yocto**.

Go through the machine tune files to understand more - https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/conf/machine/include/arm/arch-armv8a.inc

The **default** CPU and Application Binary Interface (ABI) **tunings** **are set in BSP layer (machine.conf) of your board**.

For example for Raspberry Pi 4 64 it is set here - https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/blob/ffc402ef5e9660de4db27379215fc88681d06dc7/conf/machine/raspberrypi4-64.conf#L13